# ffmpeg fails in crontab running as root

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, cron

I am trying to convert a video from mov to mp4 from a crontab.

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -nostdin -hide_banner -loglevel panic -i "/var/www/sample.mov" -vcodec h264 -acodec mp3 "/var/www/sample.mp4"
```

When I run it from a terminal it works fine. From a crontab I get the following errors. I have already tried adding "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/ && /usr/bin/ffmpeg" without success. Any help would be appreciated.

```
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x4e8290] Could not find a valid device
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x4e8290] can't configure decoder
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (h264_v4l2m2m) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Error while opening decoder for input stream #0:0 : Permission denied
```

Comment: How did you verify that the command is running as root?

Comment: I log in as root and create the crontab as root.  This is not a shared host.

Comment: I have also tried having the cron call a shell script but get the same result.

Comment: If you run `env -i sh -c '/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -nostdin -hide_banner -loglevel panic -i "/var/www/sample.mov" -vcodec h264 -acodec mp3 "/var/www/sample.mp4"'` from a terminal, can you reproduce the error outside of cron?

Answer (score 0):

As That Other Guy hinted, this was my fault.  Even though the cron was running as root, it was calling a script that was not running as root.  Once I changed it to actually run as root it all worked.